Problem with app.razor, why can't I add the @code section?
razor
@inject IVisibilityService VisibilityService

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h1>Access Denied</h1>
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code {
    private bool isActiveTab = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        VisibilityService.OnVisible += OnTabVisible;
        VisibilityService.OnHidden += OnTabHidden;
        await VisibilityService.Initialize();
    }

    private async void OnTabVisible()
    {
        // Example logic when tab becomes visible
        Console.WriteLine("Tab is visible");
    }

    private async void OnTabHidden()
    {
        // Example logic when tab becomes hidden
        Console.WriteLine("Tab is hidden");
    }
}

it keeps giving me an error:
"RZ1006 The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.  "
as if he didn't like the mountain of code itself
I want to add logic that if the tab is not active, it should close the thread so as not to waste memory.

Seems fine in the online playground I just pasted it into. Have you tried restarting visual studio? It does sometimes get the wrong idea with Blazor razor and ghost errors hang around too long. Also, just confirming this is just "code block in razor" with no separate codebehind file? Might be worth switching to a separate codebehind file; it works much better, particularly for refactoring, I find

Where you put this code? Inside the Visual studio or the Visual studio code? Have you tried reopen the VS and test again?
